# sencha Touch Chart: Is it Possible to display both Label and values in pie chart?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

Is There  any way to show value and label both in sencha pie chart? I tried in label "render", but the only parameter that come is the value or label only one at a time, But I can't get both at a time.

Please help me regarding this,

Thanks,

Nag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking to do : http://bl.ocks.org/2237197.
In the `renderer` function you have access to the `chart` variable, so you can get the store, and then you find the record corresponding to the label you are currently rendering and then you can render whatever you want !